# Previewing Video attachement Rails Admin, Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I am using ActiveStorage 5.2.3. I have one_attachment and multiple attachments relations in the same model.

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many_attached :photos

  scope :with_eager_loading_photos, -> {eager_load photos_attachment: :blob}

  attr_accessor :remove_photos
  after_save do
    Array(remove_photos).each { |id| photos.find_by_id(id).try(:purge) }
  end

  def photos_filesname
    photos.map {|p| p.filename.to_s}
  end

  def watermarked_image
    image.variant(
        combine_options: {
            gravity: 'center',
            draw: 'image Over 0,0 200,100 "' + Rails.root.join("public/watermark.png").to_s + '"'
        }
    )
  end
end
```

Everything is going well at the level of my own application.

However, I am trying to use Rails-Admin 1.4.2 also and everything is going well **except showing properly Videos preview**.

```
config.model 'Post' do
  list do
    fields :title, :content
    field :image, :active_storage
    field :photos, :multiple_active_storage do
      delete_method :delete_photos
      label 'Videos'
    end
  end
end
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see not video preview is shown. The  **photos** relations is uploading videos.

How can I configure Rails Admin for showing videos preview?

Comment: I see the preview being show, a static images is what a preview is, maybe you are expecting a video player, but the preview method will show a sample image.
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#previewing-files

Comment: If you want a video player for the preview you'll have to create your own rails admin field.

Comment: The preview you can see is about picture, no video, the videos are in the last column.

Comment: Perhaps reading the active storage field on rails admin will lead to some insight https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/active_storage.rb

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**You can try doing this with your video field, I have used active storage and its working fine on my side.**

```
row :video do |vid|
        video_tag Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(vid.video.attachment.blob),:controls=>true, :autobuffer=>true,:size => "200x150" rescue nil
end
```

[image: Video player working fine]